# Fatal Exception Android App, trying to implement Google Maps API

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm new to Java programming for Android. This is the first language I use to develop apps. 
The app is about using the Google Maps API. It is supposed to pick locations from A to B amd so on, like some sort of a treasure hunt. 
Im trying to sort out the Menu at the moment, and then this happens. I only have these xml files: Menu, Pentagram and ofc The Manifest (Mysterygame Manifest), and java files: Menu and Pentagram.

At the moment im trying to implement a google maps map on menu screen with two seperate buttons - but when I sorted the whole out with the Key from google etc, this happend.

Here is the Logcat:

```
09-24 22:32:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11739): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-576
09-24 22:32:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11739): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.mysterygame.au.Menu }
09-24 22:32:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11739): at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
09-24 22:32:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11739): at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
09-24 22:32:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11739): at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
09-24 22:32:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11739): at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
09-24 22:32:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11739): at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
09-24 22:32:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11739): at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
09-24 22:32:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11739): at com.mysterygame.au.Pentagram$1.run(Pentagram.java:29)
```

The two activities Menu & Pentagram in the Manifest:

```
// Intro Screen with the picture Pentagram
<activity
android:name="Pentagram"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>

// Menu
<activity
android:name="Menu"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.mysterygame.au.MENU" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The two Java classes:
    // Menu

```
public class Menu extends Activity {
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu); } }

  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.starting_point, menu);
    return true; } }

//Pentagram
public class Pentagram extends Activity {
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pentagram);
    Thread timer = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        try { sleep(5000); }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        finally { 
          Intent openMenu = new Intent("com.mysterygame.au.Menu");
          startActivity(openMenu); } } };
    timer.start(); }
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish(); } }
```

Thank you for your time - cheers 
Matt

Comment: Can you post the code where you call your activity? Also, have you added the activity you are trying to start to the manifest?

Comment: Just added the two activities called from the manifest

Comment: You should post the menu & pentagram code

Comment: Alright.. just a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your issue:

```
Intent openMenu = new Intent("com.mysterygame.au.Menu");
          startActivity(openMenu); } } };
```

It should be:

```
Intent openMenu = new Intent(Pentagram.this, Menu.class);
startActivity(openMenu); } } };
```

When you are using `Intent`, you need to insert the class name as I did above, not the way you did. You basically include the current Activity you are in, and the one you want to start, which is why you use `Pentagram.this` (the Activity you are in) and `Menu.class` the Activity you want to start.

Good luck.

Comment: The OnClickListener is my next thing to do, but since I cant load the menu screen, or even start the app - im screwed. hmm.. oh well. Must be some minor/major fault I have not seen yet. It all worked before I startet implementing the Google Maps API ..

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Intent is=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
startActivity(is);
```

Comment: Hi Carolin, where would I implement the new Intent ? Sorry for asking :)